# How to print in a Roll 3 label at once in crystal reoprt

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I want to print barcode labels in crystal report with 30MM x 16MM Label size paper roll, below picture
[image]

I'm using a printer model BIXOLON XD3-40t it is Thermal transfer Barcode printer, I have designed barcode label in crystal report, crystal report page setup I have defined below,

[image]

after I have set crystal report "Section Expert" and suppressed all the headers and footers and Check “Format with Multiple
Columns”. and setup the Layout and specified Width , Horizontal & Vertical Gap and than select
“Accross then Down” also below,

[image]

Printer preferences I have defined below,

[image]

The problem after done everything label printing only print middle sticker only it won't print both sides other two stickers.

printer preview only show one designed label and 3 page count separately below,

[image]

Once it prints it's coming like below,

[image]

I needs to display records in multiple columns (3 columns per row in a sticker paper roll).

Answer (score 0):

you should use the sdk of the printer and just send the command to print each text or codebar.